# 型 の引数は型 のパラメーターと互換性がありません

Tags: c

以下のコードで文字をウインドウに表示させようとしているのですが
引数の互換性が無いとエラーメッセージが表示され動きません、
言語もDXライブラリも触り始めた初心者なので教えていただきたいです

```
#include "DxLib.h"


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int) {
    ChangeWindowMode(true);//ウインドウ化
    DxLib_Init();   // DXライブラリ初期化処理
    SetDrawScreen(DX_SCREEN_BACK);//裏画面描画設定


    //
    while(ScreenFlip() == 0  && ProcessMessage() == 0 && ClearDrawScreen() == 0){

               //ここでエラーがでる
        DrawFormatString(0, 0, GetColor(255,255,255), "こんにちは"); // 文字を描画する

    }


    DxLib_End();    // DXライブラリ終了処理
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: エラーメッセージは原因を知る上でのヒントになります。エラーメッセージには何と何の型が誤っているのか説明されているはずですので、質問文にメッセージ全文を記載してください。

Answer (score 1):

すみません、プロパティの文字セットを、
マルチバイト文字セットに変更したら
エラーが出ることなく動作させる事が出来ました

Answer (score 1):

自分で対策されたように、これは`文字セット`の指定に依存します。

もう少し汎用性を持たせるなら、文字列定数`"こんにちは"`を`_T( )`または`_TEXT( )`で囲んでください。

```
DrawFormatString(0, 0, GetColor(255,255,255), _T("こんにちは")); // 文字を描画する
```

こうすることで`文字セット`の指定をデフォルトの`Unicode 文字セットを使用する`でも、変更した`マルチ バイト文字セットを使用する`でも問題無くコンパイルすることが出来ます。

もう一方で`文字セット`の指定を変えずにUnicodeだけで使うなら最初の`"`の前に`L`を付けて`L"こんにちは"`とすることも出来ます。

以下のあたりを参考に：
[Unicode プログラミングの要約](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/text/unicode-programming-summary?view=vs-2019)
[tchar.h における汎用テキストのマッピング](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/text/generic-text-mappings-in-tchar-h?view=vs-2019)

上記を含む一連の説明の先頭ページ
[Visual C++ のテキストと文字列](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/text/text-and-strings-in-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019)